# Что за библиотека или как добиться такого же результата?

Tags: android, github, lib, android-dialog

[image: первый диалог]
[image: второй диалог]

Как сделать такойже диалог как в приложении MUVIZ?
Я уже весь гугл  перерыл с гитхабом

Comment: это не диалоговое окно а кастомная view

Comment: Какой именно результат вам необходим?

Comment: Очень много примеров в просторах интернета. Погуглите ключевым словом custom fragment android или custom dialog fragment

Comment: Скоро ответы со ссылками на гугл будут..